# Choose type of ggplot2 histogram (frequency or density) within a function

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

long-time reader, first-time question-writer...I have a function that puts takes in data and spits out a ggplot2 histogram with some specific formatting. I'm trying to edit this function so that one of the function parameters can specify whether I want the histogram to show the frequency or the density of the data. I know I can specify this manually inside the `geom_histogram()` function with `aes(y=..count..)` or `aes(y=..density..)`, respectively. But I'm having issues figuring out how to access these variables if they aren't inputted directly.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
library(ggplot2)

histplot <- function(data,density=FALSE) {

  if (density) {
    type <- "..density.."
  } else {
    type <- "..count.."
  }

  theplot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=data[,1])) +
    geom_histogram(position="identity",binwidth = 2, 
               aes(y=eval(parse(text=type))))

  g <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(theplot))
  grid.draw(g)

}

xy <- data.frame(X=rnorm(100,0,10),Y=rnorm(100))
histplot(xy)
```

When I execute this function, the error I get is:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '..count..' not found
```

I can't figure out why this won't work, because if I do something like the following:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- "x"
eval(parse(text=y))
```

Then the output will be

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

My guess is it has something to do with the environments.

Comment: @Elin If you have a variable named `string`, then  `eval(parse(text="string"))` takes the character string `"string"` and executes the variable with that same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use `aes_string` in this case so something like this should work

```
type="..count.."
ggplot(xy, aes_string(x=xy[,1], y=type)) +
  geom_histogram(position="identity",binwidth = 2)
```

Comment: That seems to do it, thank you! Can you explain why what I was trying wasn't working, and why this does?

Comment: @LindsayLee It's to do with standard and non-standard evaluation. Using `aes_string()` means you can pass arguments as quoted strings, while `aes()` expects unquoted objects. Have a look at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html As a general rule of thumb if you find yourself using `eval(parse())` there's a better way!